# Weird behavior when box-selecting

Tags: camera, selection-tools

My Blender experience is about 1 week now. Anyway,...
I installed Blender on my 2 laptops. In one of them, when I do box select, selection happens, but also the object becomes camera, and the view changes to it. For example, after startup with the cube in view if I box select the cube or even empty space, the cube becomes camera and the view goes inside the cube (I think). If I change camera to camera, it goes back to cube as soon as I box-select. The other laptop behaves as I would expect.

I thought maybe I have accidentally set some weird shortcut. I have removed the installation with all preference settings I can find, and reinstalled. Also tried to copy config from the well behaving laptop. No change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can u pls provide a screenshot of you blender window? thx

Comment: added before/after shots

Comment: ok, looks like your camera is in the cube

Comment: Yes, it is - after I have box-selected an area in view. Before selecting, camera is in camera. My action is just  LMB, move mouse slightly, and release LMB. This causes camera to be in the cube.

Comment: In doubt: reinstall Blender.

Comment: tried to set factory configs, uninstall and remove all custom configs I could find, then reinstall => no change